# Android TTS in directions dialog

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I would like to make use of TTS from several Activities (one MAIN Activity can start multiple other Activities), for example I'm trying to activate from a navigation drawer the text to speech option for a navigation application.

[image]

I want to use it for telling directions to visual impaired people. Here's the dialog of directions.

[image]

It's correct to use it as a service? How can I make it like an Accessibility option?